# Series of books : The moon is really a space ship that has collected a great deal of debris

Tags: story-identification

I read this series about 10-15 years ago. It starts out with a manned flight around the moon. The ship then brings him in and he ends up being made the ship's captain by the computer. It turns out that the "Moon" is really a ship that has collected a great deal of rock and dust for several millennia.

He then goes to the "Navy Headquarters" to find that the everyone is dead and then ends up Emperor by mistake.

Comment: Wow. I would also like to read that. Can you please ping me using comments after finding the correct answer?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I'm not the OP, but since there's an answer I'm pinging you as requested.  I can definitely recommend the first two books in the series - the third goes off on a tangent.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95907/looking-for-a-book-about-the-moon-being-a-spaceship-with-an-ai (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 32):

This could be [Empire from the Ashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_from_the_Ashes) series of books by David Weber, originally published in 1991.

You can read the first book in the series (Mutineer's Moon) for free online [here](http://baencd.freedoors.org/Books/Empire%20From%20the%20Ashes/Empire_From_the_Ashes.htm)

> "For Colin MacIntyre, it began with a routine training flight over the
>   moon. For Dahak, a self-aware Imperial battleship, it began millennia
>   ago, standing guard against an unknown enemy which once devastated the
>   galaxy-and now has returned. So Dahak grabbed MacIntyre's ship and
>   informed him that he was drafted to be its new captain and lead the
>   fight against the ancient enemy.

**The moon is a moon-sized spaceship**

> *"It's not possible," MacIntyre said stubbornly. "If this thing is the size you say, what happened to the real moon?" "It was destroyed," his
>   informant said calmly. "With the exception of sufficient of its
>   original material to make up the negligible difference in diameter, it
>   was dropped into your sun. It is standard Fleet procedure to
>   camouflage picket units or any capital ship that may be required to
>   spend extended periods in systems not claimed by the Imperium."*
>
> *"You
>   camouflaged your ship as our moon? That's insane!" "On the contrary,
>   Commander. A planetoid-class starship is not an easy object to hide.
>   Replacing an existing moon of appropriate size is by far the simplest
>   means of concealment, particularly when, as in this case, the original
>   surface contours are faithfully recreated as part of the procedure."*

**He's made Emperor as part of an attempt to hack into a battle computer;**

> *"Damn it. Damn it! We need an emperor to get into the goddamned system, and the last > emperor died forty-five thousand years ago!"
>   "Captain," Dahak said after a moment, "I believe there might be a way."*
>
> *"Colin screamed in the grip of an agony too vast to endure, and yet it was over before he > could truly experience it. Its echoes shuddered
>   away down his synapses, stuttering in the racing pound of his heart,
>   and then they were gone.
>   **"Case Omega executed," Mother said emotionlessly. "The Emperor is dead; long live the Emperor!"** "*

Comment: I don't think you need to sat "This could be..."

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I generally edit that bit out when the OP accepts the answer.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, as an aside, I love this series and recommend to everyone.

Comment: Ah I see, I think the Baen site only posts the first 24 chapters, the other link posts 96 chapters.  You can get to the Baen version through the "View Sample Chapters"[here](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-127-empire-from-the-ashes.aspx)

Comment: You can find the entire Empire From the Ashes story free in one of their bundled CDs.  These CDs are explicitly licensed for free electronic sharing, and can be found [here](http://baencd.thefifthimperium.com/) - the Mission of Honor CD includes this series, as well as almost all Weber's other works.

Comment: @Jeff - Good find. I've reinstated the original link.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this might be mutineers moon, by David weber

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1107296.Mutineers_Moon

The top line description from Wikipedia is - The book’s premise is that the moon is a massive space ship controlled by a self-aware computer that wants its rightful crew back aboard.

It is part of a series of books and 'mutineers moon' is the 1st in the set, it is now available to read on line for free at the baen free library

Www.baen.com

Comment: I don't see it [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/c-1-free-library.aspx?sectionID=108) ... ?

Comment: @AE - You can read it online here; http://baencd.freedoors.org/Books/Empire%20From%20the%20Ashes/Empire_From_the_Ashes.htm