# Sci-fi trilogy: astronaut abducted on the moon (which is a spaceship), alien wars for supremacy over Earth, and longevity at the cost of fertility

Tags: story-identification, books

I had a trilogy of sci-fi books.

In the first book, an astronaut flies around the moon and then is abducted by the AI in the moon, which turns out to be a spaceship; he then gets implants to enhance his body.

There are two factions of human/aliens on Earth that are fighting for supremacy.  Over the course of the trilogy wars are fought plots to take over etc.

The main man is made emperor and has a fleet of war ships, pad to pad teleporting is in ect.

There is another race found and they give Earth's people longevity but also stop them from procreating.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95907/looking-for-a-book-about-the-moon-being-a-spaceship-with-an-ai

Answer (score 9):

## [The *Dahak* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber_bibliography#Dahak_series), by [David Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber)

1. [*Mutineers' Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutineers%27_Moon) (1991)
2. [*The Armageddon Inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Armageddon_Inheritance) (1993)
3. [*Heirs of Empire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heirs_of_Empire) (1996)

In *Mutineers' Moon*, the empty warship *Dahak* — Earth's moon — abducts Colin MacIntyre, an astronaut, to enlist Colin's help quashing the ancient (and ongoing) mutiny of the ship's crew, an event that led to the human colonization of Earth thousands of years ago.  The original mutineers have used life-extension technologies to survive into the present day on Earth.  Their descendants — most of the planet's population — are largely unaware of this old conflict.  Some of the mutineers now seek domination over Earth, while repentant mutineers oppose them.  *Dahak* gives Colin technological enhancements, promotes him to Captain, and sends him to Earth to track down the mutineers.

*The Armageddon Inheritance* deals with the re-establishment of the human interstellar empire — with Colin as Emperor due to his status as the highest-ranking officer of the reconstituted space navy — and the threat of annihilation from an alien enemy.

*Heirs of Empire*, which takes place one human generation later, follows a mixed-species team as they restore contact between the Terran branch of humanity and one of the Empire's other long-lost worlds.

These three novels are collected in [*Empire from the Ashes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_from_the_Ashes) (2003).

You can [borrow *The Armageddon Inheritance*](https://archive.org/details/armageddoninheri00webe) as an e-book from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/about/).

[image: Cover of Mutineers' Moon]
[image: Cover of The Armageddon Inheritance]
[image: Cover of Heirs of Empire]
[image: Cover of Empire from the Ashes]

---

You mentioned:

> pad to pad teleporting is in

The previous human empire (the Fourth), which had this technology late in its history, fell when the network became a vector for a plague (*The Armageddon Inheritance*). The Fifth Empire takes steps to restore the link between Earth and the capital world Birhat (*Heirs of Empire*). (Thanks to @Seretba for reminding me.)

> There is another race found and they give Earth's people longevity but also stop them from procreating.

I don't remember this, but there is something on a similar theme. The aliens in *The Armageddon Inheritance* are all cloned males.  As a means of control, the artificial intelligence that runs their society eliminated females long ago.  In *Heirs of Empire*, humans and aliens have been working to restore the lost parts of the alien genome, producing new females for the first time in millennia.

Comment: Actually, in "Armageddon Inheritance" it is discovered the previously fallen Empire had teleporting technology they used to connect solar systems. I think it is casually shown working in Heirs of Empire, a restored node linking Empire's capital and Earth.

Comment: @Seretba - Ah, right. Thank you. That's how the plague that brought down the previous empire spread so fast, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes, that was it. It is discussed at some point in third book some planets managed to shut down the system in time to be spared, but they were overrun by refugee fleets carrying the infection, with only one known exception.